# VPS debian script PHP

Tags: php, debian, vps

I just get a debian vps server for the first time and even set it cost me I succeeded.
Now I have an existential question, I want to make a php script running continuously, is to try iOS push notifications,? Can you tell me how this it?

I start my virtual console SSH and I run  / usr/bin/php5 push.php and Apple connection, this perfect works but when I close the console and I open is no longer running, I guess that when you close the session executed everything stops. What do I do for that is always running that script?

And I guess to make sure you always running should create another script to control it to restart when stopped Or am I wrong?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a couple of ways to do this.

1) start a `screen` session, so that your session stays active even when your SSH connection terminates (this is useful if you have a long-running process you want to reconnect to later).

2) use the `nohup` command (this is the simplest solution, e.g. `nohup /usr/bin/php5 push.php`).

3) get your script running properly as a service (this is the proper way to do it.  on debian you should look into using an `init` script, or similar).

if you plan on using this in the long run, you should look into option 3 :)

Comment: More thans I just try option two and it works perfect.

I'm going to do now the third option because as you have told me is the best thanks

Answer (score 2):

Run the command with the ampersand (&) this makes it run in the background

```
/usr/bin/php5 push.php &
```

Comment: Thanks friend but when i rerun the SSH an enter my password an my user and I see the process with ps -aux this process not there

Comment: if you use the ampersand, the process is forked to the background but will still be closed when you quit the login shell.

Comment: Can you add the contents of push.php

Comment: then, That I can do to not close? Thanks

Comment: who is upvoting this?